Custom OIDC authentication in Azure Functions (without ClientSecret, with extra request parameters)
I need to use OpenID Connect to authenticate to an API.

When I'm is not authenticated, I will be redirected to the login screen (*)
And after logging in I will be redirected back.

(*) Typically I'm already logged in at the Identity Provider (IDP), so I will be instantly redirected back. However, this should not make a difference.
Approach one: configuration
I've attempted to configure it through the Azure Portal, but that doe not allow me to configure an empty client secret. However, I can go to https://resources.azure.com/subscriptions/«guid»/resourceGroups/«rg»/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/«function»/config/authsettingsV2 to configure authentication. I've tried to configure it like this:
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/«guid»/resourceGroups/«rg»/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/«function»/config/authsettingsV2",
  "name": "authsettingsV2",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "location": "West Europe",
  "properties": {
    "platform": {
      "enabled": true,
      "runtimeVersion": "~1"
    },
    "globalValidation": {
      "requireAuthentication": true,
      "unauthenticatedClientAction": "RedirectToLoginPage",
      "redirectToProvider": "«idprovider»"
    },
    "identityProviders": {
      "customOpenIdConnectProviders": {
        "«idprovider»": {
          "registration": {
            "clientId": "«id»",
            "clientCredential": {
              "clientSecretSettingName": ""
            },
            "openIdConnectConfiguration": {
              "authorizationEndpoint": "https://«idprovider.net»/oauth/v1/authorize?hook_context_custom_param.applicationId=12345",
              "wellKnownOpenIdConfiguration": "https://«idprovider.net»/.well-known/openid-configuration"
            }
          },
          "login": {
            "scopes": [
              "openid",
              "companySelection",
              "email",
              "profile"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

This does take me to the login screen, however, after logging in an error occurs at my identity provider, because of the missing parameter hook_context_custom_param.applicationId. (I think the authentication for web apps allow for custom url parameters, but function apps not. My workaround of explicitly configuring the url including the parameter does not work.) I'm getting redirected to:
https://«function».azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/«idprovider»/callback?error=invalid_request&error_description=Required+parameter+code+challenge+is+missing.&state=redir%3D%252Fapi%252FDebugFunction&error_reference=FUHXTR
Approach two: in code
Like in my web app, I'm adding authentication using services.AddAuthentication like this:
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie().AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = idProviderOptions.Authority;
            options.ClientId = idProviderOptions.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = null;
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.UsePkce = true;
            options.Scope.Add("openid");
            options.Scope.Add("profile");
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("companySelection");
            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "mail";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx => OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(ctx, idProviderOptions)
            };
        });

I'm adding the parameters like this:
    private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context, IdProviderOptions idProviderOptions)
    {
        foreach (var (key, value) in idProviderOptions.CustomUrlParameters)
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter(key, value);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

However, for my web app I'm calling UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization on my web application. There's no such thing for my function app.
I've attempted to create middleware by wrapping the default AuthenticationMiddleware like this:
public class AzureFunctionsAuthenticationMiddleware(IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider) : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var innerMiddleware = new AuthenticationMiddleware(_ => next(context), schemeProvider);
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext(); // fails because this returns null
        innerMiddleware.Invoke(httpContext);
    }
}

However, this fails because the httpcontext returns null.
I've had limited success calling ChallengeAsync on IAuthenticationService in my function body, and I've been able to redirect to my authentication provider. But at that point I do not have anything listening at https://«function»/signin-oidc. If I create a function at that endpoint, the debugger is not hit and an error is returned.
What is the recommended way to configure a custom oidc-provider within function apps?

Refer https://onexception.dev/news/1384152/custom-oidc-auth-in-azure-functions
